# Communication between TabHost and it content

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tabhost

Lets imagine the following structure:

```
ActivityA ---->  contains TabHostA, Button1

TabHostA  ---->  in one of its tabs holds the ActivityB that contains TextView1
```

The TabHost is filled with an intent:

```
TabSpec tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("tab1")
        .setContent(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
mTabHost.addTab(tab);
```

And I want when the Button1 is pressed the TextView1 is changed. How can I access to TextView1 from ActivityA or communicate ActivityB and ActivityA for doing this change?

Please do no try to change the "tab-model" because it comes from a more complex problem (if interested search MapViews inside fragments) and thats the unique way it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like that?

```
((TabActivity) getParent()).getTabHost()
```

Then you can edit the TextView of the given tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BroadCastReciever` and when the `Button` is pressed, broadcast it from `ActivityA`, then in `ActivityB` which have registered itself as `BroadCastReciever` will receive the BroadCast and change the contents of `TextView`